# Change a controller variable when $stateChangeStart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI-Router and I would like to change a variable defined in a controller, every time my state is changed

```
.run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
            //I want it here (eg: dctrl.elemOne = true;)
        })
})
```

Please help me

Comment: You can write that code in your controller.

Comment: you need to create a service that will store the variable which you wanted to share among the app.

Comment: OP, The lifecycles are wrong, you can't do it that way. Controller is instantiated when the ui-views are linked (long after $stateChangeStart and even after $stateChangeSuccess).   It's also an encapsulation violation.